# A segmentation fault with UCS function

Tags: c

I'm working on a project about the N-queens game 8-puzzle for school and I'm encountering a problem for a week now. I have to implemente Uniform Cost Search function to solve the game. I implemented BFS and DFS, it worked. But with UCS I have a Segmentation fault which is probably related to my popBest function because BFS and UCS are related. Besides, the segmentation error is also related to temp in my code because there no error when I remove it. Thanks for helping me. Here's my code:

```
Item* popBest(list_t* list)
{
    assert(list);
    assert(list->numElements);
    assert(list->first);

    //  the first element is best.
    Item* best = list->first;
    int minf = best->f;

    // Search from the second element (if it exists).
    Item* item = best->next;
    while (item) {
        if (item->f < minf) {
            minf = item->f;
            best = item;
        }
        item = item->next;
    }

    delList(list, best);
    return best;
}

void ucs(void)
{
    Item *cur_node, *child_p, *temp;
    int i;

    cur_node->f = 0;

    while (listCount(&openList_p)) {
        cur_node = popBest(&openList_p);
        addFirst(&closedList_p, cur_node);
        if (evaluateBoard(cur_node) == 0.0) {
            showSolution(cur_node);
            printf("\nParcours en largeur (bfs)\n");
            return;
        }
        else {

            /* Enumerate adjacent states */
            for (i = 0; i < MAX_BOARD; i++) {
                child_p = getChildBoard(cur_node, i);
                child_p->f = cur_node->f + 1;

                if (child_p != NULL) { // it's a valid child!
                    temp = onList(&openList_p, child_p->board);

                    /* Ignore this child if already visited */
                    if (temp == NULL) {
                        /* Add child node to openList*/
                        addLast(&openList_p, child_p);
                    }
                    else if (temp != NULL && child_p->f < temp->f) {
                        delList(&openList_p, temp);
                        addLast(&openList_p, child_p);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Also, C and C++ are two *very* different languages, with different rules. What might lead to crashes in one language might be allowed in the other. So please pick the language you actually program in.

Comment: As for the crashes, a general tip to more easily figure such things out is to not write large pieces of code at once, and only write very small pieces that are tested before adding the next very small piece. I also recommend that you [learn how to debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and how to use a debugger to catch crashes and locate them in your code and to examine variables and their values.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've already run gdb and it located the crash in ucs function

Comment: Then can you please edit your question to add a comment on the line where the crash happened? And also please include details such as values of all variables at that line. And *please* try to create an actual [mcve] to show us, as it will make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: You state you have a run time problem Then show us code that does not even compile, much less execute.